# Singularities of Viehweg's fiber product

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a fibration between smooth projective manifolds. Assume that $\Delta$ is a simple normal crossing divisor in $Y$ such that $f^*(\Delta)$ is normal crossing in $X$, and 
$$
f_0:X_0=f^{-1}(Y_0)\to Y_0
$$
 is smooth. Let $
 X^r:=X\times_{Y}X\times_{Y}\times_{Y} \ldots\times_{Y} X 
 $ be the $r$-fiber product of $f:X\to Y$,  and $\pi:X^{(r)}\to X^r$ be a desingularization such that $(f^{(r)})^*(\Delta)$ is normal crossing in $X$, where $f^{(r)}:X^{(r)}\to Y$ denotes the natural projection. By Viehweg's work we know that there exists a natural morphism
$$
(f^{(r)})^*\det f_*(mK_{X/Y})\to mK_{X^{(r)}/Y}+E^{(m)} 
$$
where $r:={\rm rank} f_*(mK_{X/Y})$ depends on $m$,  $E^{(m)} $ is some effective divisor contained in $(f^{(r)})^*(\Delta)$.  This thus induces an effective divisor $\Gamma_m$ of the line bundle
$$
mK_{X^{(r)}/Y}+E^{(m)}+F^{(m)}-(f^{(r)})^*\det f_*(mK_{X/Y})
$$
where ${\rm Codim}_Y(f^{(r)}_*(F^{(m)}))\geq 2$.

Question:Is there exists  some universal constants $c\in \mathbb{N}$ such that 
for any $m\geq 1$, $cm(f^{(r)})^*(\Delta)-E^{(m)}$ is always effective?

---

Indeed, if we assume that $f$ is smooth, then the natural morphism
$$
\det f_*(mK_{X/Y})\to \otimes^rf_*(mK_{X/Y})\simeq (f^r)_*(mK_{X^r/Y})
$$
as well as the adjunction $(f^r)^*(f^r)_*(mK_{X^r/Y})\to mK_{X^r/Y}$ as Yagna said, will give  rise to the divisor $\Gamma_m$. In general, there will appear the exceptional divisor $E^{(m)}$ since the fibration is not smooth. My expectation is that, the exceptional locus $\Delta$ of $f$ can control the exceptional divisors.

---

Let me explain a bit why I expect this (if I think correctly). Let $Y_1\subset Y$ to be the maximal Zariski open set of $Y$ such that 
$$
f_1:X_1=f^{-1}(Y_1)\to Y_1
$$
is flat. Then $Y\setminus Y_1$ is of codimension 2, and
$$
X_1^r:=(f^r)^{-1}(Y_1)\simeq X_1\times_{Y_1}X_1\times_{Y_1}\times_{Y_1} \ldots\times_{Y_1} X_1 .
$$
Moreover, $f^r|_{X_1^r}$ is flat. However, since $X_1^r$ is not normal, due to certain fibers of $f$ may not be reduces. One thus has
$$
K_{X^{(r)}/Y}+E_1=\pi^*\omega_{X^r/Y}+E_2 \quad {\rm on}\quad X_1^{(r)}
$$
for some effective divisors $E_1$ and $E_2$, where $X_1^{(r)}:=\pi^{-1}(X_1^r)$. If $f^*(\Delta)$ is  simple normal crossing, then general fibers of $f$ are reduced, and $X_1^r $ is normal with rational singularities, and thus $E_1=0$. This makes the divisor $E^{(m)}=0$ in $\Gamma_m$. When $f^*(\Delta)$ has multiplicities over some components, I believe that the bad singularities of $X_1^r$ will depend on these multiplicites, and I expect that $(f^{(r)})*(\Delta)$ can control these bad singularities...

Comment: I am not entirely sure where in his work that map appears, if you could give a reference that will be fantastic. If the map you constructed is a result of adjunction morphism 
$f^{(r)^*}f^{(r)}_*\omega_{X^{(r)}/Y}^{\otimes m} \to \omega_{X^{(r)}/Y}^{\otimes m}$
and extension by reflexivity of the sheaves involved, then I do not see why the relative base locus have to be contained inside the branch locus of $f^{(r)}$ in $X^{(r)}$. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: @yagna This is the reference https://arxiv.org/pdf/1504.01095.pdf . See eq. 3.14.14, where one assumes $L^r$ and $L$ is trivial in their paper.  Since in the Viehweg's papers, he mostly dealt with the case of semistable fibrations, I cannot find a precise statement like I asked.